# Incrementing a single number in a history line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, md5

So I'm having difficulty figuring this out.

What I am trying to do, is display the most recently entered command

Let's use this as an example:

```
MD5=$(cat $DICT | head -1 | tail -1 | md5sum)
```

This command has just been executed. It is contained inside of a shell script.
After it is executed, the output is checked in an if..then..else.. statement.
If the condition is met, I want it to run the command above, except I want it incremented by one, every time it is ran.
For instance:

```
MD5=$(cat $DICT | head -1 | tail -1 | md5sum)

if test ! $MD5=$HASH  #$HASH is a user defined MD5Hash, it is checking if $MD5 does NOT equal the user's $HASH
  then  #one liner to display the history, to display the most recent
    "MD5=$(cat $DICT | head -1 | tail -1 | md5sum)" #pipe it to remove the column count, then increment the "head -1" to "head -2"
  else echo "The hash is the same."
fi  #I also need this if..then..else statement to run, until the "else" condition is met.
```

Can anyone help, please and thank you. I'm having a brain fart.
I was thinking using sed, or awk to increment. grep to display the most recent of the commands,

So say:

```
$ history 3
```

Would output:

```
1 MD5=$(cat $DICT | head -1 | tail -1 | md5sum)
2 test ! $MD5=$HASH 
3 history 3
```

-

```
$ history 3 | grep MD5
```

Would output:

```
1 MD5=$(cat $DICT | head -1 | tail -1 | md5sum)
```

Now I want it to remove the 1, and add a 1 to head's value, and rerun that command. And send that command back through the if..then..else test.

Comment: This pipe snake is not realy needed. `head -1 $DICT|md5sum` is enough.

Comment: Thank you, that is true. A good improvement, I was half asleep when I was making this.
head -1 $DICT|tail-1|md5sum
The tail is still required, I only want to display a single line of a file. So when head gets changed to -2, it would display every line before as well.

Comment: So You have a file in `$DICT` and you have a variable `HASH` and you could like to loop trrough the file and find the matching line?

Comment: Accept the answer. Don't leave it hanging.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

If I understood your problem well, this can be a solution:

```
# Setup test environment
DICT=infile
cat >"$DICT" <<XXX
Kraftwerk
King Crimson
Solaris
After Cyring
XXX

HASH=$(md5sum <<<"After Cyring")

# Process input file and look for match
while read line; do
  md5=$(md5sum<<<"$line")
  ((++count))
  [ "$HASH" == "$md5" ] && echo "The hash is the same. ($count)" && break
done <$DICT
```

Output:

```
The hash is the same. (4)
```

I improved the script a little bit. It spares one more `clone(2)` and `pipe(2)` call using `md5sum<<<word` notation instead of `echo word|md5sum`.

At first it sets up the test env creating `infile` and a HASH. Then it reads each line of the input file, creates the MD5 checksum and checks if is matches with `HASH`. If so it writes some message to `stdout` and `break`s the loop.

IMHO the original problem was a little bit over-thought.

Comment: Thank you for your time.
I'm a little confused, however. If it is reading $line form user input, that would work, if you are getting the MD5hash of a word the user inputs. The done at the end is getting input from $DICT (the file) I'm a little confused, is $line being defined by user input for the file?

Comment: @ab: I added a little bit more comment and some simplifications. Is it solves your problem?